# Sum of repeated numeric columns (array) in Bigquery

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sum, aggregate-functions

How can I get the sum of a repeated numeric column (array) in BigQuery ?

For example, from the following array:

```
SELECT [4, 5, 9] as repeated_numeric
UNION ALL SELECT [2,3];
```

| Row | repeated_numeric |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [4, 5, 9] |
| 2 | [2,3] |

I am looking for this result:

| Row | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 |
| 2 | 5 |

The length of my arrays is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below simple approach

```
select repeated_numeric, 
  (select sum(num) from t.repeated_numeric num) total
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]